# Can't update state react, returning infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

So, this is my state, and is all fine.

```
state = {
    prazoAdic: this.props.form.prazoAdicCad,
    prazoMedio: this.props.form.prazoMedio,
    tableData: [],
  };
```

This function "grupoDeVendaCheck()" needs to update the state "tableData" with the value "newObj", and this value (newObj) its good.

```
grupoDeVendaCheck = () => {
    const { current } = this.props.dropdown;

    const newPrazo = current.products.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      sf_prazo1__c: parseInt(item.sf_prazo1__c || 0) + this.state.prazoMedio,
    }));

    const newObj = Object.values(
      newPrazo.reduce((acc, el) => {
        const key = el.grupoVendas + "_" + el.sf_prazo1__c;
        if (!acc[key])
          acc[key] = {
            group: el.grupoVendas,
            term: el.sf_prazo1__c,
            value: 0,
          };
        const bruto = el.sf_quantity * el.sf_sum_of_pairs__c * el.sf_list_price;
        acc[key].value += bruto;

        return acc;
      }, {})
    );

    this.setState({ tableData: newObj }); // This is the problem

    console.log(newObj, "object");
  };
```

Above we have the componentDidUpdate, and I think that is working fine too.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (
      prevProps.form.prazoAdicCad !== prevState.prazoAdic ||
      prevProps.form.prazoMedio !== prevState.prazoMedio
    ) {
      this.setState({ prazoAdic: prevProps.form.prazoAdicCad });
      this.setState({ prazoMedio: prevProps.form.prazoMedio });
    } else if (typeof prevState.prazoAdic === "number") {
      this.grupoDeVendaCheck();
    }
  }
```

So, what is the deal, when I comment the setState on the method "grupoDeVendaCheck()" and run, he shows me the correct value of the "newObject", look:

[image]

But when I put the setState, to change the value of the state "tableData", this is the result:

[image]
[image]

I just want to update my state with this value, but I can't for some reason, I already try to use arrow inside setState, but I think I did it wrong.

If anyone can help me I would be very grateful

Comment: Hello again - If my advice was helpful, please think about selecting it as the preferred answer so that others can be helped by it too.

Comment: Oh really sorry, i forgot about it, im new at stackoverflow. It was really helpful your advice, and i will select it, thankkss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidUpdate` is called every time you use the `setState` function, so obviously you have to be very careful not to cause a loop.

Its quite hard to get my head round your code out of context, but I think is happening is:

The first condition you use is this

```
 if (
      prevProps.form.prazoAdicCad !== prevState.prazoAdic ||
      prevProps.form.prazoMedio !== prevState.prazoMedio
    ) {
```

If that is false, it calls the function `grupoDeVendaCheck()`

That function updates the state, but it only updates `tableData`

`prazoAdicCad`, `prazoAdic`, `prazoMedio` and `prazoMedio` remain unchanged so when you use `this.setState({ tableData: newObj })`, `componentDidUpdate` is called again and the condition is the same. This means `grupoDeVendaCheck` is called again.

You need to either effect the state used for the condition at the same time like this:

`this.setState({ tableData: newObj, prazoAdic: somethingNew })`
This would break the cycle

Or find another effect to trigger the 'grupoDeVendaCheck' function in the first place rather than using `componentDidUpdate`

**EDIT**
Just thinking a little more about it - it may be a good idea to move your tableData to the parent that is setting the `form` props, and update it with a callback. You would have more control at that level.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to apply here, but I understand the the reason with your explanation, thanks!!

Comment: Cool - good luck

Comment: You may also find it easier to use functional components - there is a bit of a learning curve if you haven't before, but the lifecycle methods of class-based react can be hard to work with which is why they moved away from them.

Comment: Either way I think moving your tableData to the parent component (see EDIT) would make it much easier to think about.
Very often if you are having some dance between your state and your props, you should move it up so you are only dealing with state in the parent.